# SAP UI5 - How do I display and format JSON object in the textarea?

Tags: json, sapui5

currently, I am creating the ObjectPage for my object in the SAP UI5. One of its properties is currently 'parameters' - basically, this is a stringified JSON object (I don't know which keys and values it contains, that depends on the object). Since my app is mostly for developers, I don't mind if I simply show the whole JSON content as it is (and turn the label into Textarea if they need to edit it). This is my json file

> "parameters": {
>           "operationalApi": {
>               "authUrl": "authUrl",
>               "realm": "Azeroth",
>               "apiKey": "apiKey",
>           }  },

However, I am not sure how to do it. If I use the easiest command in .cshtml

`<m:Text text="|Parameters: {/parameters}"/>`

This is what I get

```
Parameters: [object Object]
```

So I would like to ask - how can I display (and ideally also format, with indentation, new lines and stuff) the whole JSON object as it is? I wasnt able to find any kind of SAP UI5 control which would enable it.

Thank you

Comment: Have you seen the [CodeEditor control](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.codeeditor.CodeEditor)? What about using JSON.stringify in your /parameters object?

Comment: Thank you yes, toying with it right now - seems to do the job. Havent mastered that formatting yet, probably that´s what that prettyPrint method for...